# Moving a QGraphicsRectItem with mouse

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to move a QGraphicsRectItem after I add it to the scene. It moves, but appears with a certain offset from the mouse pointer. I think it is simply adding the mouse pointer position to its original position. I am at a loss as to how to work around this.

Here is my code:

```
class ucFilter : public QGraphicsItem {
    
    std::shared_ptr<QGraphicsRectItem> m_rect;
    std::shared_ptr<QGraphicsTextItem> m_text;
    std::shared_ptr<QString> m_name;
    std::shared_ptr<QPointF> m_pos;
    QGraphicsItem* selectedItem;
    
    bool m_mouseGrabbed;
public:
    static const int default_x = 80, default_y=40;
    ucFilter::ucFilter(QString &name, QPointF &pos){
        m_name  = shared_ptr<QString>(new QString(name));
        m_pos   = shared_ptr<QPointF>(new QPointF(pos));
        m_rect  = shared_ptr<QGraphicsRectItem>( new QGraphicsRectItem(pos.x()-default_x, pos.y()-default_y, 2*default_x, 2*default_y ));

        
        m_text  = shared_ptr<QGraphicsTextItem>( new QGraphicsTextItem(name));
        
        m_text->setPos(pos.x() - m_text->boundingRect().width()/2, pos.y()- 30);
        selectedItem = NULL;
        m_mouseGrabbed = false;
    }

    QGraphicsRectItem*  getRect()   { return m_rect.get();  }
    QGraphicsTextItem*  getText()   { return m_text.get();  }
    QString*            getName()   { return m_name.get();  }
    QPointF*            getPos()    { return m_pos.get();   }
    
    void                setPos(QPointF newPos)  { m_pos->setX(newPos.x()); m_pos->setY(newPos.y()); }

    QRectF ucFilter::boundingRect() const
    {
        return m_rect->boundingRect();
    }

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(widget);
        //QBrush brush(
        
        if (!m_mouseGrabbed){ grabMouse(); m_mouseGrabbed = true;   }
        
    }
    
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
        selectedItem = this;
        QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
        selectedItem = NULL;
        QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
    {
        if(NULL != selectedItem){
            m_text->setPos(event->pos());
            m_rect->setPos(event->pos());
        }
        QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);
    }

};
```

the ucFilter object is created in the scene dropEvent:

```
void cGraphicsScene::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent * event){
    
    QTreeView* source = static_cast<QTreeView*>(event->source());
    
    string name = event->mimeData()->text().toUtf8().constData();
    if(0 == name.length()){
        event->acceptProposedAction();
        return ; // nothing to do anymore 
    }
    QPointF pos = event->scenePos ();

    shared_ptr<ucFilter> newFilter = shared_ptr<ucFilter>(new ucFilter(event->mimeData()->text(),event->scenePos ()));
    m_filters.push_back(newFilter);
    this->addItem(newFilter->getRect());
    this->addItem(newFilter->getText());

    this->addItem(newFilter.get()); // also add the item to grab mouse events

    event->acceptProposedAction();
}
```

Where could the problem be ?
Here a screenshot of what I'm actually seeing : [image]

I would like the rectangle to be drawn where the mouse is..

Comment: Probably the 2 coordinates (mouse and Item) have a different origin, if I remember well the item's coords are relative to the scene, while the mouse's coords are sceeen based

Comment: precisely! how can I change this?

Comment: Woohoo `std::shared_ptr` craziness. You don't need to store any of your members as pointers. Your item owns its children and whatever other parameters you have. Store them by value. What you're doing is the most obscene case of cargo cult programming I've seen. Someone has convinced you that shared pointers are the way to go, but you don't understand why they are the way to go (and when), and just use them indiscriminately. It's really obscene. And where are your initializer lists? Passing by const reference? UURGH.

Comment: hum. I see. What if I export the ucFilter class to be used without a shared_ptr instantiation? I would then need to somehow smartpoint to the new objects I create..

Comment: One final thing: why do you have a QGraphicsItem that doesn't have any children? Aren't the `rect` and `text` supposed to be positioned relative to the `ucFilter`?

Comment: "export the ucFilter class to be used without a shared_ptr instantiation" I'm sorry but I have no idea what that means. Store things by value. What's so hard about that? It makes your life way easier.

Comment: Also: why do you grab the mouse in the `paint` implementation? That's completely broken and pointless.

Comment: yes, it is. where should I grab it? I cannot do it in the constructor because the ucFilter is at that point not yet added to the scene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several issues:

1. The use of shared pointers to hold everything is completely unwarranted. The scene acts as a container for items - just like `QObject` is a container for objects.
2. `ucFilter` doesn't have children. It holds pointers to other items, but that is unnecessary. The base item can be a rectangle itself, and it can have the text as a child. That way you don't need to handle positioning in a special fashion.
3. `ucFilter` can be movable. Don't reimplement that functionality yourself.
4. When you pass things by reference, pass them as const references unless you are intending to pass the modified value out. If you wish to change the value inside of the body of the function, you can pass it by value instead.
5. The mouse is already grabbed when you are dragging the item.

Let's start with the `ucFilter` item. It is really simple and does everything you need. Note that `m_text` is held by value, and is made a child of the rectangle parent.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/graphics-item-drop-32574576
#include <QtWidgets>

class ucFilter : public QGraphicsRectItem {
   QGraphicsTextItem m_text;
public:
   ucFilter(const QString &name, const QPointF &pos, QGraphicsItem * parent = 0) :
      QGraphicsRectItem(parent),
      m_text(this)
   {
      static const QRect defaultRect(0, 0, 160, 80);
      setPos(pos);
      setRect(QRect(-defaultRect.topLeft()/2, defaultRect.size()));
      setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
      setName(name);
   }
   void setName(const QString & text) {
      m_text.setPlainText(text);
      m_text.setPos(-m_text.boundingRect().width()/2, -30);
   }
   QString name() const {
      return m_text.toPlainText();
   }
};
```

Since we're dropping from a convenience widget (a `QListWidget`), we need to decode the text from a `application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist` mime type:

```
const char * kMimeType = "application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist";

QVariant decode(const QMimeData* data, Qt::ItemDataRole role = Qt::DisplayRole) {
   auto buf = data->data(kMimeType);
   QDataStream stream(&buf, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
   while (!stream.atEnd()) {
      int row, col;
      QMap<int, QVariant> map;
      stream >> row >> col >> map;
      if (map.contains(role)) return map[role];
   }
   return QVariant();
}
```

The scene creates an item as soon as a drag enters it, and moves the item during the drag.

Ownership of the items remains with the scene: we don't need to delete any items unless we want to explicitly remove them from the scene. The `m_dragItem` is used to refer to the currently dragged item simply to  move it and add it to `m_filters` upon completion of the drop. It the drag leaves the scene (or is aborted), the item is simply deleted from the scene.

```
class cGraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene {
   QList<ucFilter*> m_filters;
   ucFilter* m_dragItem;
public:
   cGraphicsScene(QObject * parent = 0) : QGraphicsScene(parent), m_dragItem(nullptr) {}
   void dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent * event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
      if (!event->mimeData()->hasFormat(kMimeType)) return;
      auto name = decode(event->mimeData()).toString();
      if (name.isEmpty()) return;
      QScopedPointer<ucFilter> filter(new ucFilter(name, event->scenePos()));
      addItem(m_dragItem = filter.take());
      event->acceptProposedAction();
   }
   void dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent * event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
      if (!m_dragItem) return;
      m_dragItem->setPos(event->scenePos());
      event->acceptProposedAction();
   }
   void dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent * event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
      if (!m_dragItem) return;
      m_dragItem->setPos(event->scenePos());
      m_filters << m_dragItem;
      event->acceptProposedAction();
   }
   void dragLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent * event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
      delete m_dragItem;
      m_dragItem = nullptr;
      event->acceptProposedAction();
   }
};
```

The test harness is very simple: our scene, a view displaying it, and a list with two items that you can drag onto the scene.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QWidget w;
   cGraphicsScene scene;
   QGraphicsView view(&scene);
   QListWidget list;
   QHBoxLayout l(&w);
   l.addWidget(&view);
   l.addWidget(&list);

   list.setFixedWidth(120);
   list.addItem("Item1");
   list.addItem("Item2");
   list.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragOnly);
   view.setAcceptDrops(true);

   w.resize(500, 300);
   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

You can drag items from the list on the right to the scene on the left. You can also move the items within the scene, to relocate them.

Comment: A warm thank you from the bottom of my heart, not only have you solved my problem but helped me improve my programming. Your answer is Legend.